# Linux Dialog package argument insert for/while loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dialog

What I'd like to do is to store menu items in an array and dynamically retrieve them in order to get as much reusability as I can. As following code shown, I got syntax error at `***` line. The code is derived from `Dialog` package examples.

```
function showSubMenu() {
      . ./setup-vars
      . ./setup-tempfile

      $DIALOG --clear --title $1 $2 \
       --menu "" $3 \
***    (for line in $4
        do 
          $line ""
        done) 2> $tempfile
      retval=$?
      . ./report-tempfile
}

TITLE="MyStrings"
TT= "$@"
MSG=("Linux" "Gentoo" "Arch" "Buildroot" "Ubuntu" "Debian" "RedHat")
SIZE="20 30 6"
for i in ${MSG[@]}
do
    echo $i
done
showSubMenu $TITLE $TT $SIZE ${MSG[@]}
```

My questions are:
1. Is it possible to write code like this?
2. If no, is there any other possible or similar idea for doing that?

Comment: Use shellcheck.net to fix syntax issues in your script, I could see atleast two here

Comment: After adding `\`` between `(for....)`, syntax error disappeared. The first string which is `Linux` has been regarded as argument. How to fix it?

Comment: `TT= "$@"` --> this is wrong, remove the space, `TT="$@"`

Comment: Thanks Inian, I'm afraid that's not the point. It really doesn't matter. It's in the original code, I haven't got chance to figure it out. Focus on `for loop`, would you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
    function showSubMenu() {
      . ./setup-vars
      . ./setup-tempfile

      $DIALOG --clear --title $1 $2 \
       --menu "" $3 \
    `(for line in $4
        do 
          printf "${line}"
        done)` 2> $tempfile
      retval=$?
      . ./report-tempfile
}

TITLE="MyStrings"
TT= "$@"
MSG=("Linux" "Gentoo" "Arch" "Buildroot" "Ubuntu" "Debian" "RedHat")
SIZE="20 30 6"
for i in "${MSG[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
showSubMenu $TITLE $TT $SIZE MSG[@]
```